# obtener id de un query modificado

Tags: php, mysql

Buenos días, quisiera saber si existe una función similar al msqli_insert_id (esta función devuelve la id o clave primaria del query a ejecutar), pero que se aplique después de un update.
Es decir, una función que me indique cual es la clave primaria del registro que acabo de modificar.

[image: Estructura de la Tabla]

Comment: ¿Qué es el ID **de una tabla**? @shadowmors ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta agregando un poco más de detalle y un ejemplo de lo que querrías hacer y el resultado esperado?

Comment: Al referirme como ID de una tabla, estoy mencionando su clave primaria

Comment: añade la estructura de tu tabla

Comment: [Esta respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1751282/3791844) quizás pueda ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el `Select @@identity AS`

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT @@identity AS id");
if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)) {
  $id = trim($row[0]);
}
```

Devuelve el ID del ultimo registro por lo que se utiliza despues de una insercion (`insert`)

Tambien puedes utilizar el `Max(nombre_id_tabla)`

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(nombre_id_tabla) AS id FROM nombre_tabla");
if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)) {
  $id = trim($row[0]);
}
```

Pero esta forma solo es **"util"** si utilizamos id con **auto-increment**, porque estamos suponiendo que el **ID** mas grande es la ultima insercion.

Por ultimo también existe la forma que mencionabas tu `mysql_insert_id`.

[más informacion.](https://jcvier.wordpress.com/2009/01/11/3-formas-de-obtener-el-id-del-ultimo-registro-ingresado-en-mysql-y-php-sql/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, el detalle es que lo necesito al momento de modificar, es decir:
1) actualizo una tabla, pero esta tabla esta relacionada con otras y por ende necesito su clave primaria
2) debo obtener la clave primaria de la tabla anterior para continuar con los siguientes update.

No la necesito para hacer un insert por que para eso ya uso la que mencione con anterioridad